# how to turn ExpressionStatementSyntax into ParenthesizedExpressionSyntax (put parentheses around expression)

Tags: c#, roslyn

Suppose I have  `"".GetType()` which is `ExpressionStatementSyntax` (or maybe `InvocationExpressionSyntax`) in the syntax tree and I want to turn it into `("".GetType())`, that is I want to turn my  `ExpressionStatementSyntax` node into `ParenthesizedExpressionSyntax` node. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var oldRootNode = Syntax.ParseCompilationUnit(
            "class C { void M() { \"\".GetType(); } }");
        var oldStatementNode = oldRootNode.DescendantNodes().OfType<ExpressionStatementSyntax>().First();
        var oldExpressionNode = oldStatementNode.Expression;
        var newExpressionNode = Syntax.ParenthesizedExpression(oldExpressionNode);
        var newRootNode = oldRootNode.ReplaceNode(oldExpressionNode, newExpressionNode);
        Console.WriteLine(oldRootNode.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(newRootNode.ToString());
    }
}
```